# FirebaseAnalytics log ProductAction like it was in GoogleAnalytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Good Day,

I have a method, which is used to log Google Analytics Event:

```
public void sendGoogleAnalyticsCheckoutEvent(Class className, Order order) {
        ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
                    .setTransactionId(order.getId())
                    .setTransactionRevenue(order.getGrandTotal())
                    .setTransactionTax(order.getTaxTotal())
                    .setTransactionShipping(order.getShippingTotal());

        HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                    .setProductAction(productAction);

        List<Variant> variants = order.getItems();
        for (Variant variant : variants) {
                Product product = new Product();
                product.setId(variant.getSku());
                product.setName(variant.getName());
                product.setVariant("" + variant.getVariantId());
                product.setPrice(variant.getPrice());
                product.setQuantity((int) variant.getQuantity());
                builder.addProduct(product);
        }

        tracker.setScreenName(className.getSimpleName());
        tracker.send(builder.build());
}
```

Is there any alternatives in `FirebaseAnalytics` for logging `ProductAction` and `builder.addProduct()` ?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I have the same question.